# php mysql search approach

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to implement a search on my website. Getting started, I have some beginner questions.

1. If I use a pagination script, does those scripts find all results when search is triggered and simply display the results as pages?
2. Is it better to keep the keywords in a session variable and do search, bring say 10 results everytime user hits "More results" Button?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: It is useful question for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unless you cache the results the first time the search is run, the "paged" results generally re-run the search query, then throw away the rows that aren't being displayed
2. There's no point in using a session variable to store the keywords, unless you don't plan on displaying the search box alongside the results (e.g. as Google search result pages do).

Comment: Understood #1. About #2, I was thinking: If I save the keywords, then I can limit the search to say 10 results, and if user clicks on 'more', I can redo a search LIMIT 10,20. Or you think that is not a good idea?

Comment: that'd be part of #1, actually.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Getting started on it now.